# WordPress / WlooCommerce Variable Not Being Passwed Through Within A Function / Hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I have post meta on a woocommerce that is meant to capture a ID that is used when displaying a shortcode with PHP.

As you can see here

```
// Add Preview Button To Product Pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'add_preview_button_to_mag_issues' );
function add_preview_button_to_mag_issues() {
    if (has_term( 'Magazine Issues', 'product_cat' )){
        $fb_prev_issue_sc_var = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'fb_prev_issue_shortcode', true); // Store Shortcode To Display Preview Flipbook
        //echo do_shortcode('[real3dflipbook id="2"]');
        echo do_shortcode('[real3dflipbook id="' . $fb_prev_issue_sc_var . '"]'); // Print Shortcode To Display Preview Flipbook
        echo '<a class="real3dflipbook-lightbox button alt">Preview Issue</a>'; // Print Button To Open Lightbox
    }
}
```

The variable $fb_prev_issue_sc_var is not getting content for some reason. I've used this same exact method of filling the variable previously in my code and it works fine and it was for displaying the same shortcode... however it was not in a "hook" or function.

Here is how I am saving the variable

```
// Preview Issue Shortcode ID
$woocommerce_fb_prev_issue_shortcode = $_POST['fb_prev_issue_shortcode'];
if( !empty( $woocommerce_fb_prev_issue_shortcode ) )
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'fb_prev_issue_shortcode', esc_attr( $woocommerce_fb_prev_issue_shortcode ) );
```

Cant figure this one out...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT
Note both these lines of code are contained within the child themes functions.php file

Comment: Try to make $post global within add_preview_button_to_mag_issues(); as you're trying to read ID of $post which might be undefined up to that point.

Comment: @Burimi ahhhhhh that's exacly what I was looking for!! If you want to post a answer saying that I will pick you as best answer thanks bud!

Comment: Just posted the answer as it might help other users as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the variable `$post` global, as you're trying to read attribute ID of an undefined object.

Having WordPress debug enabled would helped in this case.